# Getting Steam Market Values AJAX Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I am trying to get the data from say: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20M4A1-S%20|%20Hyper%20Beast%20(Minimal%20Wear)
Which contains something like this:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"65,84\u20ac","volume":"21","median_price":"65,19\u20ac"}
```

My code so far:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20M4A1-S%20|%20Hyper%20Beast%20(Minimal%20Wear)",
type: "GET",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
});
```

But I am getting the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: may be you have invalid json

Comment: @uzaif I am getting the json data from http://steamcommunity.com

Comment: in which line console error display?

Comment: @uzaif steamcommunity.com/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: click on that error which will lead you in error section